# Angular 5 - Using jsp with Angular cli fails

Tags: jsp, angular-cli, angular5

I am using Angular5 with angular cli. I have provided my entry point as my jsp page which contains scriptlet tags. When I build this I get error as

Child compilation failed : Module build failed: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token.

Here is a sample of my angular-cli.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "sample"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src/main/webapp/app",
      "outDir": "src/main/webapp/dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.jsp",
      "main": "main.ts"
    }
}
```

Is it possible to change the entry point to a jsp page? If so how should it be referenced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the similar issue and came up with a workaround by using a JSP to wrap the index.html which is generated by Angular app.

So my angular-cli.json looked like this

```
{
   "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
   "project": {
      "name": "sample"
   },
   "apps": [
      {
          "root": "src/main/webapp/app",
          "outDir": "src/main/webapp/jsp/myapp/files",
          "assets": [
              "assets",
              "favicon.ico"
          ],
          "index": "index.html",
          "main": "main.ts"
      }
   ]
}
```

Then I created src/main/webapp/jsp/myapp/index.jsp. My index.jsp looked like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>My App</title>
      <base href="/jsp/myapp/">
   </head>
   <body>
      <jsp:include page="files/index.html"/>
   </body>
</html>
```

Then you can launch your app by hitting /jsp/myapp/ or /jsp/myapp/index.jsp.

Hope it helps.